# Normalise range of values of array without knowing min/max values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to arrange the values of an array to have a range of 0.0 - 1.0. but without having to know the min and max values of the array in advance. Say I have this below.

`Event:7.3339,5.20755,25343052,11.8282,-1,1,146511,-0.584812,1.41411,1.23406,-2.27636,6.23602,2.3905,2.06042,-1.55016,5.8858,-1.81976,-3.85836,4.62525`

So in the future I want to make sure it will be normalized to the given range by finding the min/max values programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the `min` and `max` values and for every value subtract the `min` value and divide by the delta of `max` and `min`.

`toFixed` is only for displaying the normalised values.

```js
function getNormalized(array) {
    var min = Math.min(...array),
        max = Math.max(...array);

    return array.map(v => (v - min) / (max - min));
}

var array = [7.3339, 5.20755, 25343052, 11.8282, -1, 1, 146511, -0.584812, 1.41411, 1.23406, -2.27636, 6.23602, 2.3905, 2.06042, -1.55016, 5.8858, -1.81976, -3.85836, 4.62525];

console.log(getNormalized(array).map(v => v.toFixed(10)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That looks great how could I translate this to a function, I get this now when I run it enclosed in a function -> _Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or false values_ I know this might look awful but I am trying to achieve this following the example.                                                         `var array = function() {
                min = Math.min(...reformattedArray),
                max = Math.max(...reformattedArray),
                result = reformattedArray.map(v => (v - min) / (max - min));
                return result;
            };`